# Connection String for Local Network

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-connection, connection-string

I've got a local working connectionstring which is displayed below but I need a little change in it to make it applicable for a network. 
I've tried to do it with a static ip but it didn't work. Already checked that the connection to the other device is stable.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<configSections>
</configSections>
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="BeursTD.Properties.Settings.sdtcaptConnectionString"
        connectionString="Data Source=levi\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=sdtcapt;User ID=XXXX;Password=XXXX"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using something like

```
connectionString="Server=192.168.1.1,1433; Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=mbc;User ID=xxxx;Password=xxxxx"
```

This points to the specific computer running the DB on the network

1433 is the default port for SQL server, so if yours is different you will need to change it.

This is used on SQL Server 2014